# How to create SUBSTITUTE function formula using REGEX

Tags: formula, regular-expressions

I need to use a formula in Process Builder to populate a string field, and in this I need to replace all special characters with dashes. I've tried numerous ways but can't seem to get it right.

What I'm trying to do is to put a REGEX of NOT("[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+") where all the xxxxx are to replace all special characters in the Name.

```
SUBSTITUTE([Account].Name,xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,'-')
```

I have a validation rule (see below) on the field at the moment which works - if it finds a special character it throws an error. This returns a boolean - how do I use it in the substitute formula?

```
NOT(REGEX(Web_slug__c , "[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+"))
```

Comment: Hi Irene, if your question is how to formulate a regex for your specific use case, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is probably a better site for asking this, I would also encourage you with posting what you have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: It's specific to my Salesforce formula, hence posting it here. I'm using Process Builder where if the field is blank, it populates it with the string returned by the formula.

Comment: "I've tried numerous ways but can't seem to get it right." please post what you have tried then. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula syntax is not powerful enough to do as you wish. You would necessarily need to resort to a simple Apex Trigger. At a basic level, it would look something like this:

```
trigger StripSpecialCharsFromName on Account (before insert, before update) {
  for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Name != null) {
      record.Name = record.Name.replaceAll('[^a-zA-Z0-9_+-]','-');
    }
  }
}
```

If you absolutely wanted to avoid writing code, you'd have to write a complicated flow to examine every character in the string and remove it based on your condition. A solution involving nothing but Process Builder/Flows would require far more work than the above trigger, and would also time-out on even trivially-sized bulk operations.

Comment: Thanks - that answers it then. I already have a trigger but was wondering whether I could do it via Process Builder. Will put it into my trigger :)

Answer (score 0):

Most regular expression varieties support the concept of a negated character class, where the regex engine will attempt to match a character that is not one of the characters listed. Typically the notation is `[^ ... ]`. I believe in your situation, you would want to use:

```
[^-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+
```

---

As far as I know, the `SUBSTITUTE()` function in salesforce formula fields can only operate on literal text strings, and won't match text based on a regular expression.